# Apex Standard Library Symbol Table

Tags: apex, tooling-api, documentation

The ability to query a symbol table for a custom apex class is great, but can we obtain this information for standard classes?  I have tried things like...

```
SELECT SymbolTable FROM ApexClass WHERE Name = 'PageReference'
```

...but this doesn't work since only custom Apex Classes are stored in the ApexClass table.  Right now i'm thinking about crawling the documentation to obtain a list of static and instance methods, class-by-class, but im wondering if this data is already available somewhere or can be obtained through API calls?

Comment: The standard classes would (I assume) be pre-compiled. Without extended reflection support I don't think you can programatically extract the list of methods etc... If you could extend PageReference you could force the derived class to be compiled. I wonder what MavensMate and the Force.com IDE does for code completion.